# Chroot to centos 6.x fails in Arch Linux 4.15.1.2

Tags: centos, arch-linux, chroot

I reported a [bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/57336) for this issue. Does anyone know what can be the cause? One of the suggested solutions is to enable `vsyscall`. I tried `vsyscall=emulate` in boot parameter but still, I got the segfault. Can I do try this using `sysctl`? What else could be the problem here?

PS: chroot'ing into a `Centos 6.x 32bit` works, so does `Centos 7.x 64bit`.

Comment: The Linux kernel in CentOS is quite a lot older so I suggest that may be the problem. Also: Describe the problem here, do not rely on external links to describe the problem!

Comment: Thanks @Ned64, it was a long stack trace to paste here. Thanks for the pointer though, it makes sense.